# How to do basic DOM manipulation (clear content, append to content) with YUI?

Tags: jquery, dom, yui

I am doing a project with YUI where I attempt to do things I have previously been doing with jQuery. I am finding it difficult to do some basic operations, and namely:

1. clear content of DOM element
2. append to content of DOM element

In jQuery, I would do:

```
$(".someSelector").empty().append("<div>something</div>");
```

How to do the above in YUI? Seems like it defers to W3C DOM spec in many aspects, I am not very familiar with that spec. If there's any specific W3C or such material I should use, please give specific links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the YUI documentation for Dom methods.
[Yahoo! UI Library > dom  > YAHOO.util.Dom](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.util.Dom.html#method_get)
Or try

```
YAHOO.util.Dom.get("somediv").innerHTML("<div>something</div>");
```

Comment: Yeah, looks like I just have to manipulate innerHTML. Somehow the jQuery API feels more elegant.

Answer (score 3):

YUI does not seem to provide the same level of DOM manipulation that jQuery does (although I haven't played with YUI3 yet, so this may change).

innerHTML definitely works, and was faster once upon a time, although I think this is changing in some modern browsers.  Appending content is easy enough via the standard methods:

```
element.appendChild(childElement);
```

Clearing is a little more involved.  I have actually ended up extending the YUI DOM utility and added this as a method:

```
removeChildren : function(elem)
{
    var theElement = this.get(elem);
    var elemChildren = theElement.childNodes;
    var childCount = elemChildren.length;
    for (var i = childCount -1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        theElement.removeChild(theElement.childNodes[i]);
    }
}
```

It's important to note than when looping through the child nodes, I start with the last element and work my way to the front.  This is because whenever a node is removed, the size of the array changes.  Also, if I remove the node at position [0], all the elements of the array move down a position (meaning the element that was at position [1] now becomes the element at position [0]).  If I was to start at the front of the array, I would miss elements, and quickly exceed the array's boundary.